# Minimum number of Trips

Tags: algorithm, graph, dynamic-programming, graph-algorithm

I have `latitude` and `longitude` points of `N societies`, `order count` of these societies, I also have `latitude` and `longitude` points of a warehouse from where the trucks will deploy and will be sent to these various societies(like Amazon deliveries). A truck can deliver `maximum 350 orders` (order count < 350). So no need to consider items with order count above 350 (We generally would send two trucks there or a bigger truck). Now I need to determine a pattern in which the trucks should be deployed in such a way that a minimum number of trips occur.

Considering that we determine the distance between two societies or warehouses is 'X' from [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27928/calculate-distance-between-two-latitude-longitude-points-haversine-formula) script is accurate, How do we solve this? I first thought that we could solve it using sum of subset problem, maybe? Seems like dp on graphs to me, traveling salesman problem with infinite number of salemans.

There are no restrictions on the number of trucks.

[image: Table // Don't consider other columns.]

Comment: I would aim at a good solution, not necessarily the best.

Comment: What have **YOU** tried so far? Share **YOUR** findings.

Comment: @Henry I did what you said and fortunately managed to find the solution to this, Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a typical Travelling salesman problem (TSP) which is known as NP-complete. It means that if you are looking for the optimal solution you have to test most of combinatorics. And as you know, !350 is tremendeous.

Nevertheless, as Henry suggests, you can look for a good solution which is not necessarily the best. A lot of algorithm called "heuristic" let you find one good solution in a very efficient way. Just have a look here for some examples https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Travelling_salesman_problem.

The most simple heuristic algorithm may be a greedy solution like always take the closest unvisited point as next society.

Comment: Thank you, this did help me to find the solution to this. https://pastebin.com/81SRjuKw this is my code, head over to line 39 for the algorithm part.

Comment: @NamanChikara Hum you should consider to use numpy. This would make your code a lot faster and simpler.

Comment: My prof told me to do the same, Thanks :)